# Unsigned Long Long from Double in Swift

Tags: swift, double, unsigned-long-long-int

I used to use the following in Objective-C:

```
double currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

// self.startTime is called before, like     
// self.startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

double elapsedTime = currentTime - self.startTime;

// Convert the double to milliseconds
unsigned long long milliSecs = (unsigned long long)(elapsedTime * 1000);
```

In my swift code I have at the moment:

```
let currentTime: Double = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
let elapsedTime: Double = currentTime - startTime

let milliSecs: CUnsignedLongLong = elapsedTime * 1000
```

However I get the error that a `double` cannot be converted to a `CUnsignedLongLong` which makes sense. Is there a way to cast it like in Objective-C though? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Is there a way to cast it like in Objective C though? Is there a way around this?

```
let milliSecs = CUnsignedLongLong(elapsedTime * 1000)
```

Or

```
let milliSecs = UInt64(elapsedTime * 1000)
```

Answer (score 6):

`CUnsignedLongLong` is defined in the standard library by:

```
typealias CUnsignedLongLong = UInt64
```

So to convert a `Double` to `CUnsignedLongLong`, you need to create a new instance of `CUnsignedLongLong` using

```
CUnsignedLongLong(elapsedTime * 1000)
```

or

```
UInt64(elapsedTime * 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift doesn't allow for implicit type conversion. Create the value using the constructor for its type.

```
let milliSecs = CFUnsignedLongLong(elapsedTime * 1000)
```